# Packaging a suite of UWP apps

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, packaging

I’m having a suite of uwp apps, say app1, app2, app3. These Apps communicate with each other via app service. Without app1, app2 & app3 can’t work. Assume app1 as accounts service app which provides authtoken for app2 and app3. Now I want to bundle all the 3 apps into a single package and when user downloads from the store all the 3 apps should be installed. How can I achieve this in UWP store/packaging. Please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I want to bundle all the 3 apps into a single package and when user downloads from the store all the 3 apps should be installed.

No, it is not possible to do that if you want to upload your app to the store.
But there is a way that might be possible to work if your app is a side-loaded app.

You could try to modify the manifest to include multiple Applications in the [Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-applications?redirectedfrom=MSDN) section. When the user installs the package they'll get all of the apps.
Please remember this only works for the sideloaded app as I mentioned previously.